# Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040015

Tags: java, android

I am inflating R.id.itemView in order to add it to a gridLayout:

```
View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.itemView,null);
```

However, I am getting this error when inflating it:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040015 type #0x12 is not valid
```

That resource number corresponds to  itemView (I checked it on R.java).
Here is the file where itemView is located (color_view.xml in res/layout):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.colors"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/itemView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/color_shape" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried cleaning,building and deleting R.java but it doesnt solve the problem. What is the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't supply an id to the first argument of `inflate`, that can only be a **layout**. You can only inflate a layout like this:

```
View item = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.color_view,null);
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout= inflater.inflate(R.layout.color_view, null);
View viewtoadd = layout.findViewById(R.id.itemView);
```

you done the use the viewtoadd; cheers